# SMTP sendmail with HTML in Matlab

Tags: html, matlab, smtp

I am trying to send emails via SMTP in Matlab. This guide is a good starting point to get started:

https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/sending-email.html

It boils down to the following lines of code (tested in 2016b):

```
setpref('Internet','E_mail','youraddress@yourserver.com');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','mail.server.network');

sendmail('recipient@someserver.com','Hello From MATLAB!','body text here');
```

However, the default SMTP does not support HTML. I tried the following:

```
sendmail('recipient@someserver.com','Hello From MATLAB!','<strong style="color:red">HTML test</strong>');
```

How can I enable HTML? Is this something simple as setting certain preferences/encoding?

Comment: from the doc **The sendmail function does not support HTML-formatted messages. However, you can send HTML files as attachments.**

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sendmail.html

> The sendmail function does not support HTML-formatted messages. However, you can send HTML files as attachments.

I guess you need to raise this with their support for an enhancement.

Comment: Oops- Just saw Andrea has already replied to this too. Thank you! 
Anyways, hope you got the correct answer.